# Does losing reputation lead to losing privileges?

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges

Imagine that a user reaches 10K reputation and gains the **moderation privilege**. Now he can edit posts immediately. The day after he gets a vote down for one of his answers/questions. Will he lose his moderation privilege? Or is it given to him anyway?

My concern is because I think for either way it has some problems. In example above there isn't any problem if the given privilege is not taken back, but what if the loss of reputation is due to a spam user's removal (that was created by the user to generate fake reputation)?

Comment: Just for the record, moderation privileges are 10k, not 2k (editing posts isn't a mod-only thing)

Comment: @Dennis: If I recall, moderation privs are 2k on beta sites.

Comment: Who honestly gets to a certain reputation and then stops earning reputation? Like a lot of people, I earn reputation every day on answers I wrote months ago... I think if the user is inactive enough that losing reputation due to a down-vote, deleted question, etc. causes them to lose privileges that is probably for the better. I do not want someone who is not an active participant on the site moderating, but that might just be me.

Comment: @Krampus Ah true, didn't think about beta sites. Still wanted to point out that editing posts isn't a moderator-only thing though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, privileges are always dependent on what reputation you currently have.

Let's say you're in a football team, you have team **A**, **B** & **C**.

You move all the way up to team **A** but then you become very bad at football, and therefore you move down to **C**, you don't stay in with the good footballers in team **A** just  because you were once that good.

Comment: Shouldn't this same argument apply to losing medals if some things get reversed? (serial voting for one)

Comment: No, medals are different that's why stackoverflow has it's own medals.  they're called badges.

Comment: I was using the terms interchangeably. My query still stands

Comment: badges and medals represent where/what you have been, reputation and team represent where/what you currently are

Comment: It is taken into account where you don't get the badge again if you lose the requirements and then gain them again